# Stop modal from closing on outside click

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Is there anything that can be done to make keep a `Modal` open when clicking outside the container?

I have a password change screen and I need the `Modal` to ONLY close when clicking on the `submit`button. which only becomes active when certain conditions are met.

```
<div>
            <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
                <Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Title>Change Password</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <form className="form-horizontal" style={{margin:0}}>
                        <div className='password-heading'>This is the first time you have logged in.</div>
                        <div className='password-heading'>Please set a new password for your account.</div>
                        <br/>

                        <label className="password">Password
                            <input type={this.state.type} className="password__input" onChange={this.passwordStrength}/>
                            <span className="password__show" onClick={this.showHide}>{this.state.type === 'input' ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}</span>
                            <span className="password__strength" data-score={this.state.score} ><div className="strength_string">{this.state.strength}</div></span>
                        </label>
                        <br/>
                        <label className="password">Confirm Password
                            <input type={this.state.type} className="password__input" onChange={this.passwordStrength}/>
                        </label>

                    </form>
                    <br/>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button onClick={this.submitPassword} disabled={this.state.isDisabled}>Submit</Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </div>
```

**UPDATE**
Appart from adding `backdrop={ 'static' }` you will most likely still be able to close the modal by clicking the `Escape` key.
To prevent this add one more thing to your modal window: `keyboard={ false }`.

This should suffice in keeping the modal open.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Set the modal's backdrop to static. The modal component has a prop of `backdrop`, set that to `backdrop="static"`

```
<div>
    <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose} backdrop="static">
        <Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Title>Change Password</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
            <form className="form-horizontal" style={{margin:0}}>
                <div className='password-heading'>This is the first time you have logged in.</div>
                <div className='password-heading'>Please set a new password for your account.</div>
                <br/>

                <label className="password">Password
                    <input type={this.state.type} className="password__input" onChange={this.passwordStrength}/>
                    <span className="password__show" onClick={this.showHide}>{this.state.type === 'input' ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}</span>
                    <span className="password__strength" data-score={this.state.score}>
                        <div className="strength_string">{this.state.strength}</div>
                    </span>
                </label>
                <br/>
                <label className="password">Confirm Password
                    <input type={this.state.type} className="password__input" onChange={this.passwordStrength}/>
                </label>

            </form>
            <br/>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.submitPassword} disabled={this.state.isDisabled}>Submit</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
</div>
```

From the documentation:

> Specify 'static' for a backdrop that doesn't trigger an "onHide" when clicked.
>   [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/)

Answer (score 3):

**Remove onHide from the Modal**  `onHide={this.handleClose}`

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass the `onHide` or `onClose` props.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to achieve the same thing and adding this `<Modal keyboard={false} ...>` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use React and Ant Design with the modal in my project. I found the anwser should be `maskClosable={false}`， please refer to the [Modal document](https://ant.design/components/modal) from Ant Design official website:
[image]

Wish to help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ReactModal like me you can use shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={false} like so

```
 <ReactModal
      open={open}
      onRequestClose={handleRequestClose}
      shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={false}
 >
```

ref: https://reactcommunity.org/react-modal/